# What does “elicit” mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does “elicit” mean in this context?

> Did they **elicit** participation from a range of people who had different views of the decision?

Is it proper to translate “elicit” here as “entail” or “include”?

I've checked the dictionary, but the translation didn't seem right to me as “draw out” or “evoke”, so I wanted to know if it is proper to translate it as “entail” or not.

Comment: Here, the verb 'elicit' means: deduce.

Comment: @MaulikV It does not.

Comment: This is a [dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/elicit) question.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree that this appears off topic as a [“question . . . entirely answerable with a dictionary”](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary) but for now I’m just going to assume this (new) user looked up the word before writing out the question and that some confusion remained. I remain hopeful that [Corabict](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3341/corabict) will return and clarify the exact nature of this dictionary-resistant confusion if that is indeed what we have here.

Comment: Yes sir I've checked the dictionary but the translation didn't appeal to me as draw out or evoke so i wanted to know is it proper to translate it as entail or not & now i know i can't do that. but tell you the truth if i said deduce participation i won't understand it without Mr damkerng last line that they want participation

Comment: Corabict: When asking a question, it's important to summarize the research you've already done. If I asked, "What does _snazzlefram_ mean?" the question would be closed, because that's a job for a dictionary, not ELL. But if I asked, "What does _snazzlefram_ mean? I looked it up in three dictionaries, and know it refers to an animal similar to a leopard, but then I saw a book where that said: _It's raining snazzleframs and lupines,_ and that doesn't make any sense," that question could remain open, because the source of confusion is clearly identified, and a dictionary can't answer it.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because I believe that *elicit* is being used questionably in this sentence, and so dictionaries won't be of much help. You can motivate someone to participate, and you can make a comment or take an action which elicits a response from someone. Something which is elicited is something that is latent within the person and is then made public in response to something, as if it were "pulled out".  Participation does not fit the idea of elicitation. You can elicit from someone their *motivation* to participate, but not participation itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Elicit” means:

> [*evoke or draw out (a response, answer, or fact) from someone in reaction to one's own actions or questions*](https://www.google.com/search?q=elicit).

In this situation, the best replacements would be “[educe](https://www.google.com/search?q=educe)” or “[garner](https://www.google.com/search?q=garner)”.

The sentence is asking if some people (“they”) got responses from a diverse group of other people. Presumably, the alternative would be to have participation only from people who share one view.

---

Replacing “elicit” with “entail” would not work, since “entail” means:

> [*involve (something) as a necessary or inevitable part or consequence.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+entail)

Replacing “elicit” with “include” would not work, since “include” means:

> [*make part of a whole or set.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+include)

Comment: *garner* is ok, not so much *induce.*  In this instance I think the best replacement for *elicit* is '*go out and get*' or '*go out and ask for*'.  *induce* connotes *cause to happen by application of some stimulus*

Comment: @Jim I agree. I meant “educe”.

Comment: @Corabict I agree with Jim that “garner” is the better replacement. Also, please note correction of “induce” to “educe” and mark answer as _accepted_ if you have no further questions on the matter. Lastly, please add details to your question, such as why you are looking for a replacement word, what definitions you found when you looked up this word and why they didn't satisfy you. Otherwise, the question will probably be voted closed.

Comment: Ok i'll make sure to correct my self next time, sorry for the mess, & thank you for helping me

Comment: @Corabict Don't feel bad! I'm just trying to give you the tips that I believe will make your stay (and I hope you will stay) here as pleasant and productive as possible.

Answer (score 2):

From Google, the verb **elicit** means,

> evoke or draw out (a reaction, answer, or fact) from someone.

The quote *"Did they elicit participation from a range of people who had different views of the decision?"* asks if they drew participation from a range of people (who had different views of the decision).

This simply implies that the person who asked this wants participation from people with different opinions.